# How to make absolute positioned elements move with the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, positioning

When I absolute position an object, it is stuck there. When you resize the browser window, it stays there while the other objects slide around, thus killing the whole point.

Now this is only for me. Obviously it works on normal websites, such as the one your on right now. when you resize the window everything moves around and stays in its overall template.

How can I achieve this with absolute positioning?

Comment: Why **must** you use absolute positioning? What it sounds like you're describing is a css liquid layout.

Comment: sorry agian, but what is css liquid layout? and I guess I dont have too, its just easier. That guys answer worked though VV

Comment: A liquid layout is a technique used to make the webpage expand (*liquid*) the size of the browser, including resizing. Do some research and you'll see what I mean. Also, I have no idea who "that guy" is.

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

Comment: thanks that helped! and that guy is Rob W, but the method is a bit flawed. this should work better. thanks agian!

Comment: That should've said "expand (*liquid*) **with** the size of the browser".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to put the absolutely positioned div inside a relatively position div. Anytime the relatively positioned div moves, the absolute positioned div will also move with it.

```
<div class="relative" >
    <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
</div>

.relative{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:blue;
}


.absolute{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    top:30px;
    left:50px;
}
```

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/w2EMu/**

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to avoid absolute positioning. But if you use it and want to reposition your absolute object you could register a resize method. E.g. [jQuery.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and reposition it yourself. If you are not using jQuery you have to use [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [document.attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).